# How to take info from Canvas python?

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, canvas

So, I'm new to web scraping and I'm having trouble getting information from the canvas.
In this [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ff37n.png) you can see the plot with the information I need to take (gray frame). This whole plot is a canvas and so I can't take the price and date information I want. Can anyone help me extract information from the plot. Thank you. Site: https://steamcommunity.com/market/listings/730/Clutch%20Case

Comment: If you inspect that element you can see that it is using a library called jqPlot. From a quick glance at the a usage example, it seems you provide the data to it in JS so it most likely is making network requests for the data when it loads. I would suggest trying to find the JS file that feeds that library data to get a direct url to the data, that way you do not need to scrape the website.

Comment: Thank you very much